# Fix message only showing for a split second pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with pygame where I'm trying to show a game message but it just resets the background after the user clicks enter, thus resulting in the game message being shown only for a split second.

I gather user input in a while loop (because I only need it to run three times) and use pygame.event.poll() to detect incoming inputs such as keyboard input etc. So the way I made it is that when the user presses enter it'll evaluate the data entered and show a game message if the input is correct or not. However, the game message will just be removed in a split second since its in a while loop. Is there any way I can make it so that the game message shows up until I click enter again?

Here is the shortened version of the code:

```
        while bad_input < 3:
            screen.blit(Variables.bgImage, [0, 0])

            ...

            ...
            e = pygame.event.poll()

            ...

            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                # Add a character
                textBox.AddChar(pygame.key.name(e.key))

                ...

                # If the user presses return,
                elif e.key == K_RETURN:
                    # And if the text size was more than 0
                    if len(textBox.text) > 0:
                        user_input = textBox.text.lower()
                          if result[0]:
                               showGameLog("Correct!")
                          else:
                               showGameLog("Hm, not quite.")
                               bad_input += 1
                       textBox.text = ""
                       # Then update the textbox
                       textBox.Update()
            pygame.display.update()
```

and here is the code for the showGameLog function:

```
def showGameLog(txt):
    text = font.render(txt , True, Color.black)
    screen.blit(logText, [25, 570])
```

Here's a video on how the problem looks like:
[problemvid](https://streamable.com/gbqud3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a state `showText`:

```py
showText = False
```

Set the state when <kbd>RETURN</kbd> is pressed, but reset the state if <kbd>RETURN</kbd> and `showText == True`:

```py
elif e.key == K_RETURN:
    if showText:
        showText = False
    elif len(textBox.text) > 0: # And if the text size was more than 0
        showText = True
        # [...]
```

Show the game log, dependent on the state of `showText`, in the main application loop:

```py
if showText:
    if result[0]:
        showGameLog("Correct!")
    else:
        showGameLog("Hm, not quite.")
```

Likely you want to skip any input as long the game log is shown:

```py
if e.type == KEYDOWN:
    if not showText:
        # Add a character
        textBox.AddChar(pygame.key.name(e.key))
```

Example code:

```py
showText = False

while bad_input < 3:
    screen.blit(Variables.bgImage, [0, 0])
    # [...]    

    e = pygame.event.poll()
    # [...]

    elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
        if showText:
            if e.key == K_RETURN:
                showText = False
        else:
            # Add a character
            textBox.AddChar(pygame.key.name(e.key))
            # If the user press space, add a empty text and update the textbox.
            if e.key == K_SPACE:
                textBox.text += " "
                textBox.Update()
            # If the user presses backspace, delete a character
            elif e.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                textBox.text = textBox.text[:-1]
                textBox.Update()
            # If the user presses return,
            elif e.key == K_RETURN:
                # And if the text size was more than 0
                if len(textBox.text) > 0:
                    showText = True
                    # [...]
                    user_input = textBox.text.lower()
                    if not result[0]:
                        bad_input += 1
                    textBox.text = ""
                    # Then update the textbox
                    textBox.Update()

    if showText:
        if result[0]:
            showGameLog("Correct!")
        else:
            showGameLog("Hm, not quite.")

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! I've tried the code and it seems to work fine, but apparently when I enter a correct input, it evaluates the input multiple time, resulting in a number of "Correct" texts showing on the gamelog. I've tried to find why and it seems that it's related to showText being true for a while.

Comment: Yeah, I included that, but I didn't really like how it looked on my end so I removed that part.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it still evaluates to true long enough that it detects the word entered as first correct then a duplicate. I'll try to figure that part on my own, Thanks a lot for the help though.

EDIT: I found out the solution! Thanks a lot!!